# Having problems with rounding integers in C

Tags: c, integer, double, rounding

I have an exercise that tell me these:

Functions
Problem 1
Function `floor` may be used to round a number to a specific decimal place. The statement

```
y = floor( x * 10 + .5 ) / 10;
```

rounds x to the tenths position (the first position to the right of the decimal point). The
statement

```
y = floor( x * 100 + .5 ) / 100;
```

rounds x to the hundredths position (the second position to the right of the decimal
point).

Write a program that defines four functions to round a number x in various ways

a. roundToInteger( number )
b. roundToTenths( number )
c. roundToHundreths( number )
d. roundToThousandths( number )

For each value read, your program should print the original value, the number rounded to
the nearest integer, the number rounded to the nearest tenth, the number rounded to
the nearest hundredth, and the number rounded to the nearest thousandth.

Input Format
Input line contain a float number.

Output Format
Print the original value, the number rounded to the nearest integer, the number rounded
to the nearest tenth, the number rounded to the nearest hundredth, and the number
rounded to the nearest thousandth

Example:

Input
24567.8
Output
24567.8 24568 24570 24600

My solution (which is wrong) is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double roundToInteger(double number)
{
   double roundedNum;
   roundedNum = floor(number + .5);
   return roundedNum;
}

double roundToTenths(double number)
{
   double roundedNum;
   roundedNum = floor(number * 10.0 + .5) / 10.0;
   return roundedNum;
}

double roundToHundreths(double number)
{
   double roundedNum;
   roundedNum = floor(number * 100.0 + .5) / 100.0;
   return roundedNum;
}

double roundToThousandths(double number)
{
   double roundedNum;
   roundedNum = floor(number * 1000.0 + .5) / 1000.0;
   return roundedNum;
}

int main()
{
  double userInput = 0.0, userInput1 = 0.0, userInput2 = 0.0,userInput3 = 0.0, userInput4 = 0.0, originalVal = 0.0;

  printf("Enter a double value: ");
  scanf("%lf", &userInput);

  originalVal = userInput;

  userInput1 = roundToInteger(userInput);

  userInput2 = roundToTenths(userInput);
 
  userInput3 = roundToHundreths(userInput);
 
  userInput4 = roundToThousandths(userInput);
 
  printf("%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf", originalVal, userInput1,userInput2,userInput3, userInput4);
}
```

What in the formula I am doing wrong?

Comment: The example output doesn't match the problem description. So which is correct, the problem description, or the example?

Comment: Are you rounding to the nearest hundred, or hundredth, for example?

Comment: It seems like you've mixed up two different exercises. One for rounding to decimal places, the other for rounding to powers of 10.

Comment: The `floor(number * 100.0 + .5)/100.0` trick results in the wrong answer for many FP values.  Why use `floor()` as `round()` is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input is `24567.8` and the expected output is `24567.8 24568 24570 24600`, change your formulas from:

```
y = floor( x * 10...0 + .5 ) / 10...0;
```

To:

```
y = floor( x / 10...0 + .5 ) * 10...0;
```

In other words, you implemented correctly the formulas provided. Only thing wrong here is the fact the formulas are wrong for rounding powers of ten. Those are for rounding decimal places.

Comment: This approach can fail to round correctly with `x < 0`.  It also can fail when `x * 10...0 + .5` is inexact due to rounding.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, excellent points as always. Do you have an example for the first case? I tried a bunch of negative numbers and all seamed to work.
For the second case, do you mean when the number does not have an exact IEEE 754 representation? I've never went deep into rounding, it looks something worthwhile to learn.

Comment: Try `int main(void) { double x = 0.49999999999999994; printf("%.17g\n", x); x = roundToInteger(x); printf("%.17g\n", x); }`.  What output do you get? What was expected?

Comment: Try `printf("%.17g\n", roundToInteger(1.5)); printf("%.17g\n", roundToInteger(-1.5));` What output do you get? What was expected?

Comment: With this answers `double roundToTen(double x) { return floor( x / 10.0 + .5 ) * 10.0; }`, try `printf("%.17g\n", roundToTen(15)); printf("%.17g\n", roundToTen(-15));`.